# POST works on Postman, but not with CURL

Tags: php, curl, postman

Using postman, I send a POST to (my username and password are filled in):

```
https://ssl.reddit.com/api/login?api_type=json&user=XXX&passwd=XXX&rem=True
```

I receive a response containing a modhash and a cookie.  Then, I send a second POST with postman to:

```
https://en.reddit.com/api/comment?api_type=json&text=7/1/15TEST&thing_id=t1_csa56v2
```

with the following headers (XXX has been confirmed and filled in):

```
User-Agent: XXX
Cookie: reddit_session=XXX
X-Modhash: XXX
```

This provides the correct response, but when I try to do the same thing with CURL in my PHP, it responds with USER_REQUIRED.  Once again, I have confirmed that the cookie and modhash are correct.

```
$name = 't1_csa56v2';
$text = 'NEWEST TEST 7/2/15 12:20am';
$url = 'https://en.reddit.com/api/comment';

$modhash = 'XXX';
$cookie = 'XXX';

$headerFields = array (
    'User-Agent' => 'XXX',
    'Cookie' => 'reddit_session='.$cookie,
    'X-Modhash' => $modhash 
);

$postFields = array (
    'api_type' => 'json',
    'text' => $text,
    'thing_id' => $name
);


$field_string = http_build_query($postFields);

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headerFields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 3);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $field_string);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

What am I doing wrong?  Why can't I get the same response?

Screenshot of POSTMAN:
[image: Screenshot of POSTMAN]

Comment: You are sending username and password in query with url (Its like sending GET request).
With Curl you are sending POST request.

Comment: @NeerajVerma Oh, sorry, I forgot to include that you can specify with postman to send a POST

Comment: But just specifying send POST request is not enough. You need to send POST data. But here you are sending data in URL.

Comment: So I added the post fields to the URL params section listed after the POST option, and it automatically spit out the URL that I pasted here, I am 99% sure thats where I add the post params

Comment: It will be helpful if you can share a screenshot of postman request. Or try to use the same url with CURL request. As URL using with postman and with CURL is not same. I mean send the data in URL query while making CURL request.

Comment: @NeerajVerma screenshot added

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82162/discussion-between-neeraj-verma-and-radleybobins).

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$name = 't1_csa56v2';
$text = 'NEWEST TEST 7/2/15 12:20am';
$url = 'https://en.reddit.com/api/comment';

$modhash = 'XXX';
$cookie = 'XXX';

$headerFields = array (
    'X-Modhash' => $modhash 
);

$postFields = array (
    'api_type' => 'json',
    'text' => $text,
    'thing_id' => $name
);



$ch = curl_init($url);
assert(curl_setopt_array($ch,
array(
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => true,
        CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION => true,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE => false,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 11,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING=>"",
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT=>'XXX',
        CURLOPT_COOKIE=>'reddit_session='.$cookie,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER=>$headerFields,
        CURLOPT_POST=>true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS=>$postFields,
)));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

try this.. not sure exactly what you do wrong, but user agent should be set with CURLOPT_USERAGENT , and the cookie should be set with CURLOPT_COOKIE and you should let curl encode it for you, rather than using http_build_query 
, and you should explicitly set it to a POST request, as its a GET request by default. should also enable E_ALL error reporting

Comment: thanks so much for answering! I unexpectedly had to travel yesterday and today, I will try out your tips as soon as possible when I get back. Just didn't want you to think I was ignoring you!

Comment: Thanks for this, wasn't able to do a request added user agent and worked.